# What is your favorite data visualization blog?

Tags: data-visualization, references

What is the best blog on data visualization?

I'm making this question a community wiki since it is highly subjective.  Please limit each answer to one link.

---

***Please note the following criteria for proposed answers:***

> [A]cceptable answers to questions like this ...need to supply adequate descriptions and reasoned justification. A mere hyperlink doesn't do it. ...[A]ny future replies [must] meet ...[these] standards; otherwise, **they will be deleted without further comment**.

Comment: i suggest everyone put their favourite image from the blog, so it's not just a collection of links...

Comment: With the maturation of this site, we now understand that acceptable answers to questions like this (to all questions, really) need to supply adequate descriptions and *reasoned justification.*  A mere hyperlink doesn't do it.  I encourage previous respondents to beef up their replies and will insist that any future replies meet our current standards; otherwise, **they will be deleted without further comment**.  I also encourage community members to upvote the *well formulated* replies in recognition of the value they add.

Comment: @whuber While I thoroughly appreciate what you're trying to do (and regret that I wasn't better at asking the question originally), I think that may not be the best approach.  It's highly unlikely that the top voted answers will be improved, in which case we will simply be littering the internet by promoting less good blogs just because the answers have more detail.

Comment: I'd also suggest since it is CW we should feel free to edit replies to provide a more thorough description. That is the point of CW right!

Answer (score 19):

[FlowingData](http://flowingdata.com/) | Data Visualization, Infographics, and Statistics

Answer (score 17):

[Information Is Beautiful](https://informationisbeautiful.net/) | Ideas, issues, knowledge, data - visualized!

Comment: I love that blog!

Answer (score 11):

[information aesthetics](https://web.archive.org/web/20120101181841/http://infosthetics.com/) - Data Visualization & Information Design

Answer (score 9):

[Junk Charts](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/) is always interesting and thought-provoking, usually providing both criticism of visualizations in the popular media and suggestions for improvements.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a blog, but Edward Tufte has an [interesting forum](http://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a?topic_id=1) on information design including data visualization.

Answer (score 4):

[EagerEyes](http://eagereyes.org)  by Robert Kosara (~5 posts a month). This blog includes tutorials and discussion articles plus it has a great home page with lots of links to useful information.

Answer (score 4):

https://web.archive.org/web/20120102041205/https://datavisualization.ch/
by Benjamin Wiederkehr and others (~15 links a month). If you want heaps of links you can subscribe to their twitter feed twitter slash datavis (~5 links a day)

ahhh... i'm a new member and so i can only post one link per post.

Answer (score 4):

[Chart Porn](http://chartporn.org/)

I find the blog name pretty humorous. Great dataviz.

Answer (score 4):

Andrew Gelman doesn't limit himself to visualization, but he comments on it frequently.

[Statistical Modeling, Causal Inference, and Social Science](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/blog/)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [data visualization blog](http://blog.visual.ly) from [Visual.ly](http://blog.visual.ly).

Answer (score 2):

I see all my favorite blogs have been listed. So I'll give you this one:

[I Love Charts](http://ilovecharts.tumblr.com/)

It's a bit light hearted.

Answer (score 2):

Light-hearted: [Indexed](http://thisisindexed.com/)

Also, see older visualizations from the same creator at the original [Indexed Blog](http://indexed.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 2):

[Dataspora](https://web.archive.org/web/20120102015341/http://dataspora.com/blog/), a data science blog.

Answer (score 2):

I can't pick just one :)

**Check out this great blog post by flowingdata:** [37 Data-ish blogs you should know about](http://flowingdata.com/2009/05/06/37-data-ish-blogs-you-should-know-about/)

Comment: Here's an updated article with blogs that are active and worth reading in **2012**: http://flowingdata.com/2012/04/27/data-and-visualization-blogs-worth-following/

Answer (score 1):

[We Love Datavis](http://datavis.tumblr.com/), a data visualization tumblog.

Answer (score 1):

I only recent became aware of the [chartsnthings](https://web.archive.org/web/20120122122656/http://chartsnthings.tumblr.com/) blog, which is about (direct quote from site);

> A (personal) blog of data sketches from the New York Times Graphics Department.

I believe I follow most of the blogs listed here so far in my feed reader, and this one is a bit different. It is more of a behind the scenes look at the development of the [NYT Graphics department](http://twitter.com/#!/nytgraphics), whom produce a wide array of excellent graphics (in a wide array of mediums) for the New York Times. Just those related articles should be followed, and are frequently mentioned in the other "discussion" sections of blogs like flowingdata or chartporn.

It is different because it describes some of the workflow of developing graphics, including initial brainstorming ideas (including ones that don't pan out). And it is certainly interesting to see the developmental stages and reasoning behind certain graphical choices. Note it isn't an instructional blog. They don't provide code R or Flash to replicate graphics, they don't give tutorials on how to use Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

A daily [dataviz](https://web.archive.org/web/20140805091005/http://dadaviz.com/) feed for/by data nerds.

The community is closed but you can request via twitter to have your account enabled.